# THINKPAD T61 : How do I boot from USB?

Tags: thinkpad, bios

I'm trying to install Lubuntu (18.0.4) on an old Lenovo Thinkpad T61 (with factory specs).

I made a bootable USB with the distro using Rufus 3.4.1430, but the BIOS just does not recognize the USB stick (it is recognized on other PCs).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of frustration, I managed to solve the problem.

The point is that the Thinkpad's BIOS does not recognize USB flash drives as a valid bootable option. It just does not!

Solution : use a USB Hard Drive instead. Make it bootable with the distro of your heart (I recommend Lubuntu, since the T61 is kinda out of the game), and *voilà*! It's the same as using a USB flash drive.

**Added note** : I had to use the 32bit version. Even if the 64bit installed properly, it refused to boot! The 32bit version runs like a charm!

Comment: Also, in Rufus, make sure you use "MBR" partitionning, and in the advanced options, make sure "Add fixes for old bioses" is checked (the name might somewhat differ, I use the french version of Rufus).